# How to delete a file in git at different stages in the commit process

Tags: git

What is the proper way to delete a file from Git in these cases?

**Case 1:** I created a new file, but I haven't done `git add new_file.html`
**Solution:** I can just delete new_file.html from my computer.

**Case 2:** I created a new file, I have done `git add new_file.html`, but I have not committed these changes.
**Solution:** ?

**Case 3:** I created a new file, I have done `git add new_file.html`, I have done `git commit -m 'added a new file here!'`.
**Solution:** ?

**Case 4:** I created a new file, I have done `git add new_file.html`, I have done `git commit -m 'added a new file here!'`, and I have merged this branch with **master** branch. 
**Solution:** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case 2

```
git reset HEAD new_file.html && rm new_file.html
```

For case 3

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

For case 4, just revert the commit

```
git revert HEAD # git revert <commit-id>
```

Comment: Thanks dmp (actually my initials...) what is the command for case 4?

Comment: git revert <commit-id> (that will make a new commit that reverts the one in <commit-id>).  You can of course use git revert HEAD in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For cases 3 and 4, there is `git rm <file>`. Aside from that, dmp's answer covers it pretty well.